# How can I load all nodes (and their children) in a TreePanel in one request?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am trying to create a TreePanel that loads all its items (and their children) in a single request at creation.  From everything I read if items have a "children" property they shouldn't attempt to load children again when expanded, however mine do.

```
Ext.define('ec.view.MarketGroupTree', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
requires:[
    'Ext.tree.*',
    'Ext.data.*'
],

xtype: 'market-group-tree',

store: Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    autoLoad: true,
    root: {
        expanded: true
    },
    fields: ['marketGroupName', 'children', 'marketGroupID'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'backend/market.php?a=marketGroupTree',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'records'
        }
    }
}),

rootVisible: false,
rowLines: true,
sealedColumns: true,
singleExpand: true,
useArrows: true,
headerPosition: 'left',
lines: false,

columns: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'treecolumn',
                dataIndex: 'marketGroupName',
                flex: 1
            },
            {
                xtype: 'treecolumn',
                dataIndex: 'marketGroupID',
                flex: 0.3
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

A sample bit of JSON as received from backend/market.php?a=marketGroupTree is:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "records":[
      {
         "marketGroupID":"2",
         "marketGroupName":"Blueprints",
     "iconID":"2703",
     "hasTypes":"1",
     "leaf":false,
     "children":[
        {
           "marketGroupID":"204",
           "marketGroupName":"Ships",
           "iconID":"2703",
           "hasTypes":"1",
           "leaf":false,
           "children":[
              {
                 "marketGroupID":"205",
                 "marketGroupName":"Frigates",
                 "iconID":"2703",
                 "hasTypes":"1",
                 "leaf":false,
                 "children":[
                    {
                       "marketGroupID":"261",
                       "marketGroupName":"Caldari",
                       "iconID":"0",
                       "hasTypes":"1",
                       "leaf":true
                    },
                    {
                       "marketGroupID":"264",
                       "marketGroupName":"Minmatar",
                       "iconID":"0",
                       "hasTypes":"1",
                       "leaf":true
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "marketGroupID":"206",
                 "marketGroupName":"Cruisers",
                 "iconID":"2703",
                 "hasTypes":"1",
                 "leaf":false,
                 "children":[
                    {
                       "marketGroupID":"273",
                       "marketGroupName":"Minmatar",
                       "iconID":"0",
                       "hasTypes":"1",
                       "leaf":true
                    },
                    {
                       "marketGroupID":"274",
                       "marketGroupName":"Amarr",
                       "iconID":"0",
                       "hasTypes":"1",
                       "leaf":true
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "marketGroupID":"209",
           "marketGroupName":"Ship Equipment",
           "iconID":"2703",
           "hasTypes":"1",
           "leaf":false,
           "children":[
              {
                 "marketGroupID":"210",
                 "marketGroupName":"Turrets & Bays",
                 "iconID":"2703",
                 "hasTypes":"1",
                 "leaf":false,
                 "children":[
                    {
                       "marketGroupID":"286",
                       "marketGroupName":"Hybrid Turrets",
                       "iconID":"2703",
                       "hasTypes":"1",
                       "leaf":false,
                       "children":[
                          {
                             "marketGroupID":"289",
                             "marketGroupName":"Large",
                             "iconID":"0",
                             "hasTypes":"1",
                             "leaf":true
                          },
                          {
                             "marketGroupID":"290",
                             "marketGroupName":"Medium",
                             "iconID":"0",
                             "hasTypes":"1",
                             "leaf":true
                          }
                       ]
                    },
                    {
                       "marketGroupID":"287",
                       "marketGroupName":"Projectile Turrets",
                       "iconID":"2703",
                       "hasTypes":"1",
                       "leaf":false,
                       "children":[
                          {
                             "marketGroupID":"296",
                             "marketGroupName":"Small",
                             "iconID":"0",
                             "hasTypes":"1",
                             "leaf":true
                          },
                          {
                             "marketGroupID":"297",
                             "marketGroupName":"Medium",
                             "iconID":"0",
                             "hasTypes":"1",
                             "leaf":true
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "marketGroupID":"214",
                 "marketGroupName":"Hull & Armor ",
                 "iconID":"2703",
                 "hasTypes":"1",
                 "leaf":false,
                 "children":[
                    {
                       "marketGroupID":"335",
                       "marketGroupName":"Hull Upgrades",
                       "iconID":"0",
                       "hasTypes":"1",
                       "leaf":true
                    },
                    {
                       "marketGroupID":"1536",
                       "marketGroupName":"Armor Repairers",
                       "iconID":"0",
                       "hasTypes":"1",
                       "leaf":true
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "marketGroupID":"4",
     "marketGroupName":"Ships",
     "iconID":"1443",
     "hasTypes":"1",
     "leaf":false,
     "children":[
        {
           "marketGroupID":"391",
           "marketGroupName":"Shuttles",
           "iconID":"1443",
           "hasTypes":"1",
           "leaf":false,
           "children":[
              {
                 "marketGroupID":"393",
                 "marketGroupName":"Amarr",
                 "iconID":"0",
                 "hasTypes":"1",
                 "leaf":true
              },
              {
                 "marketGroupID":"394",
                 "marketGroupName":"Minmatar",
                 "iconID":"0",
                 "hasTypes":"1",
                 "leaf":true
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "marketGroupID":"1361",
           "marketGroupName":"Frigates",
           "iconID":"1443",
           "hasTypes":"1",
           "leaf":false,
           "children":[
              {
                 "marketGroupID":"5",
                 "marketGroupName":"Standard Frigates",
                 "iconID":"1443",
                 "hasTypes":"1",
                 "leaf":false,
                 "children":[
                    {
                       "marketGroupID":"61",
                       "marketGroupName":"Caldari",
                       "iconID":"0",
                       "hasTypes":"1",
                       "leaf":true
                    },
                    {
                       "marketGroupID":"64",
                       "marketGroupName":"Minmatar",
                       "iconID":"0",
                       "hasTypes":"1",
                       "leaf":true
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "marketGroupID":"1362",
                 "marketGroupName":"Faction Frigates",
                 "iconID":"1443",
                 "hasTypes":"1",
                 "leaf":false,
                 "children":[
                    {
                       "marketGroupID":"1365",
                       "marketGroupName":"Pirate Faction",
                       "iconID":"0",
                           "hasTypes":"1",
                           "leaf":true
                        },
                        {
                           "marketGroupID":"1366",
                           "marketGroupName":"Navy Faction",
                           "iconID":"0",
                           "hasTypes":"1",
                           "leaf":true
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "metaData":{
      "rootProperty":"records"
   },
   "num_sent":2
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the fact that I used "records" as the root.  It appears that if you change the name of the root that also changes where children are looked for so each item should have a "records" property with its children, not a "children" one.

Comment: Yes, it is written in [the docs](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore). Look at the "Reading Nested Data" section. Thanks for taking the time to leave an answer for others :)